# How to keep hover styling even after an element is clicked? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, opacity

I have four button elements that have hover styling (from 0.2 opacity to 1 opacity). And then, I am using jQuery so that after clicking the specific button, its opacity becomes 1 (sort of a marker that it's the clicked button) and the other unclicked buttons have an opacity of 0.2.

However, after clicking, since I have forced every unclicked button to have opacity of 0.2, the css hover styling no longer works.

I created a codepen demo below:

jQuery:

```
var $box_each = $(".boxes img");
    $box_each.click(function() {
        $box_each.css("opacity", "0.2");
        $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    });
```

http://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/Bjzjrx

How do I resolve this issue so that the hover styling for all is retained while having just one element that has opacity of 1 at any given time?

Comment: apply a focus style : `.boxes img {opacity: 0.2}  .boxes img:focus {opacity: 1}` if the img won't focus, add a `tabindex=0` attrib

Comment: `How to keep hover styling even after an element is clicked?` :) You don't need to use jquery for that. [pen without jquery](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxLxZN) Its working already.

Comment: I want to have an opacity of 1 for the currently clicked element only while the rest have 0.2 opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hover effect is not working after clicking because you are giving inline styling in Jquery.

You can do something like following:

```
var $box_each = $(".boxes img");

$box_each.click(function() {
        $box_each.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Css:

```
.boxes img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.boxes img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.boxes img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWrWvd)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```js
var $box_each = $(".boxes img");

$box_each.click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $(this).addClass("unclicked");
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("unclicked");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $box_each.css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
```

```css
.boxes img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.boxes img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.clicked {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.unclicked {
  opacity: 0.2 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
</div>
```

Comment: i think this is you wnat..!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retain the opacity effect so as to apply for multiple images, I think you can try something like this.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">
  <img class="boxes-normal" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
  <img class="boxes-normal" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
  <img class="boxes-normal" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
  <img class="boxes-normal" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/">
</div>
```

#### css:

```
.boxes-normal{
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.boxes-normal:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.boxes-opaque{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var $box_each = $("#boxes img");

$box_each.click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('boxes-normal')){
      $(this).removeClass('boxes-normal');
      $(this).addClass('boxes-opaque');
    } else if($(this).hasClass('boxes-opaque')){
      $(this).removeClass('boxes-opaque');
      $(this).addClass('boxes-normal');
    }
    });
```

Hope this helps..

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrxLO)